# Retrieve data from a SQL Server stored procedure into a List<T>

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, generic-list

I have this project that I am creating a library to handle all the data from multiple projects, I have organized the queries in stored procedures. I need to pass 4 parameters to the store procedure and get back some data. I cannot believe there is no easy way to accomplish this.

I have tried the datareader, datatable I do not want to have to iterate through the data as it does have the possibility to grow large.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Dapper http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

It's a micro ORM, **much** faster than EF - written by and used by guys behind SO ;-)

*Note*: `I do not want to have to iterate through the data as it does have the possibility to grow large` - someone will *have to* iterate through the result set - either you or the framework you will be using. Consider paging if you think you might get too much data at once.

Comment: Ef for stored proceudres has no performance hit. You are calling the SP, not doing any selects, its not building queries. EF is building complex types for your SP's so you dont have to iterate through the result set.

Comment: @bugnuker - I do not agree - see http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ for performance tests of SELECT mappings, that is converting resultset into objects and not performance of generating SQL from expression tree.

Comment: Like i said before, EF is NOT doing the select. the SP has the select. You are calling "exec SP" and SQL returns a result set.

Comment: Yes, sproc has the actual T-SQL SELECT statement, but it's the EF code that processes the byte sent from the server. Unless you use SqlCommand and SqlReader directly, skipping any EF code - and that's what Dapper is doing...

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is nice.
Add new item > ADO.NET entity Model
Generate from database
select only the SP's, unless you want to import the table schema too.

Once it finds your SP's, it will create complex types for you and everything will be really easy.

entity Framework for the win.

Comment: thanks but because this is a library and it is reusable, it is unknown to which database or stored procedure it will use, that will be controlled by the controller.